# I'm using function ExportTableau() I create new PDF('L') how I change format of pdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I have problem with format of pdf when I use `$pdf=new FPDF('');` it's allowed this error

> Call to undefined method FPDF::ExportTableau()

so when I use this one `$pdf=new PDF('L');` the format of pdf turned what can I do? I check for solution but I didn't found anything can someone help!

[this is the problem the pdf is Turned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi75c.png)

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../fpdf17/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
//Chargement des données
function LoadData($file)
{
//Lecture des lignes du fichier
$lines=file($file);
$data=array();
foreach($lines as $line)
$data[]=explode(';',chop($line));
return $data;
}

//Tableau coloré
function ExportTableau($header,$data)
{
//Couleurs, épaisseur du trait et police grasse
$this->SetFillColor(150,180,255); //fond des entetes de colonnes
$this->SetTextColor(0); //couleur du texte des entetes des colonnes
$this->SetDrawColor(0); // couleur des bordures
$this->SetLineWidth(.3); //epaisseur des traits
$this->SetFont('','B');

//En-tête
$w=array(35,20,50,20,45);
for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
    $this->Cell($w[$i],5,$header[$i],1,0,'C',1);
$this->Ln();

//Restauration des couleurs et de la police
$this->SetFillColor(224,235,255); //couleur du fond des cases
$this->SetTextColor(0); //couleur du texte des cases
$this->SetFont('');

//Données
$fill=false;
foreach($data as $row)
{
    $this->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[2],6,$row[2],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[3],6,$row[3],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[4],6,$row[4],'LR',0,'L',$fill);

    $this->Ln();
    $fill=!$fill;
}
$this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');
}
}
}
}
$pdf=new PDF('L');
$pdf->AddPage();
.
.
```

Comment: `$pdf=new PDF('P');` L=landscape, P=portrait

Comment: @Dagon it's work thank you so much i spend 3 h for resolve this problem how know that's just i need to change just L with a P .

Comment: its well documented - but i guess you missed that